# SQL Server 2008 R2, HASHBYTES SHA256 returning NULL

Tags: sql-server, sha256

SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2), `HASHBYTES` `SHA2_256` returning *NULL*. Not sure if there is any settings to be configured to enable it. I understand SHA2_512 works on or above SQL 2012. But SHA2_256 should work in SQL 2008. Help me understand here please.

Below is the screenshot showing I am on 2008 R2.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from [**MSDN**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx)

> 256 bits (32 bytes) for SHA2_256, and 512 bits (64 bytes) for SHA2_512
>   applies to SQL Server 2012 through SQL Server 2016.

that's why  you are getting `null`.

Comment: Thanks. My mistake of not reading the MSDN article correctly.